# Perform web search in android

Tags: android

I have a text view. What I want is when I select the text in the textView, I give an option to users to search that word or whatever on the web. How can I do that?

Comment: Check this: [Android – How to implement Google Search inside application?](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-how-to-implement-google-search-inside-application/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent search = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);  
search.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "android how to use websearch");  
startActivity(search);
```

Comment: is above thing is possible for our webview?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` and `SearchManager.QUERY,`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
 String search = editTextInput.getText().toString();
 intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, search);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is above thing is possible for our webview?